# Set position one after another until a whole box is filled

Tags: java

So i need to update the position of my object which in this case is just a 1x1 pixel square. I need to set its position at the top of the map which is just a larger square then change the X until it reaches 50 which is the size of the map. Then it needs to change Y by one so then it goes right and X turns to one then Y changes by one again and turns to left again and so forth and so forth.

I need to do this :

This is a little example:

```
You are the cross.
|=========|
|         |
|    +    |        
|         |
|=========|

Then i need to do this:
|=========|
|+----->\/|
|\/<------|        
|------->+|
|=========|
```

My current code is this:

```
String split[] = s.split(" ");
radiusX = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
radiusZ = radiusX;
int valX = 0;
int valY = 0;
while(valX <= radiusX && valY <= radiusY) {
      valX = valX + 1;
      valY = valY + 1;
}
```

But right now that just sends the player to the corner of the map.

Comment: not sure if I got the problem right... but you are only incrementing valX and valY. That way right move will happen. Shouldn't you decrement it to move left?

Comment: Well it can move how ever but it just needs to go through every part of the square untill its full.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is walking in a diagonal by adding to X and Y at the same time. If you want to make some sort of spiral movement, you need two loops, one for altering the X value and an inner loop for the Y value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will give you a good idea of what needs to be done.

Basically you need a current position (x,y) and an increment vector.
By changing the increment vector you tell your cross/point where to go next.

This code can be generalized and made even more concise but that would 
probably make it more cryptic and will not illustrate the main idea.

```
/**
 * Represents a radius-vector in 2D. 
 * Also it is reused for representing a 2D
 * point (through its radius-vector).
 */
class Vector {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Vector(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class Test033 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // x is the column index
        // y is the row index

        int x;
        int y;

        // these define the sizes of the grid
        int x_min = 1;
        int x_max = 4;
        int y_min = 1;
        int y_max = 6;

        // we start from this point
        x = x_min;
        y = y_min;

        Vector pos = new Vector(x, y); // represents the position (x,y)
        Vector inc = new Vector(1, 0); // represents the increment (on both x and y)

        boolean start = true;
        int cnt = x_max * y_max;
        int k = 0;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println(String.format("x/col = %d y/row = %d", pos.x, pos.y));

            if (!start && inc.x == 1 && pos.x == x_max) {
                inc.x = -1;
                inc.y = 0;
                pos.y += 1; // y position
            } else if (!start && inc.x == -1 && pos.x == x_min) {
                inc.x = 1;
                inc.y = 0;
                pos.y += 1; // y position
            } else {
                pos.x += inc.x;
                pos.y += inc.y;
            }

            start = false;
            k++;
            if (k >= cnt){
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```